# How to give a file path in code instead of command line

Tags: c#, file-io

I've been working on my module exercises and I came across this code snippet which reads the text file and prints the details about it.

It's working fine, but I just want to know how to give the path of the text file in the code itself other than giving the path in the command line.

Below is my code.

```
class Module06
{
   public static void Exercise01(string[] args)
    {
        string fileName = args[0];
        FileStream stream = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Open);
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream);
        int size = (int)stream.Length;
        char[] contents = new char[size];
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        {
            contents[i] = (char)reader.Read();
        }
        reader.Close();
        Summarize(contents);
    }

    static void Summarize(char[] contents)
    {
        int vowels = 0, consonants = 0, lines = 0;
        foreach (char current in contents)
        {
            if (Char.IsLetter(current))
            {
                if ("AEIOUaeiou".IndexOf(current) != -1)
                {
                    vowels++;
                }
                else
                {
                    consonants++;
                }
            }
            else if (current == '\n')
            {
                lines++;
            }
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Total no of characters: {0}", contents.Length);
        Console.WriteLine("Total no of vowels    : {0}", vowels);
        Console.WriteLine("Total no of consonants: {0}", consonants);
        Console.WriteLine("Total no of lines     : {0}", lines);
    }
}
```

Comment: This code does not use the .NET framework effectively.  Okay for a language book I guess.  But be sure to get another book that focuses on the framework.  That's the other 90% you have to learn.

Answer (score 2):

In your `static void Main`, call

```
string[] args = {"filename.txt"};
Module06.Exercise01(args);
```

Answer (score 1):

Reading of a text file is much easier with [File.ReadAllText](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.readalltext.aspx) then you don't need to think about closing the file you just use it. It accepts file name as parameter.

```
string fileContent = File.ReadAllText("path to my file");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string fileName = @"path\to\file.txt";
```